# Discord.js with discord.js-commando Prevent command from running in specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to prevent users from entering commands in a specific channel and have no feedback whatsoever on that channel.

First I tried simply returning at the start of the run method:

```
public async run(message: CommandMessage): Promise<Message | Message[]> {

    if (message.channel.id === process.env.NUMBER_CHANNEL_ID) return;
    [...]
}
```

This works but only for commands that don't take in arguments. My issue is that I have commands that take in arguments and if I write the same line for that command, the command doesn't get run as it should (great!). However if a user doesn't put in any arguments or puts in wrong  arguments, the bot will prompt the user to enter a correct value.

The message:

> Respond with cancel to cancel the command. The command will automatically be cancelled in 30 seconds.

My question would be to figure out if there was a way to have absolutely no reaction from the command handler and or commands in a specific channel using the commando framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the answer.

While setting up the bot in your main .js file you can do the following:

```
client.dispatcher.addInhibitor((message: CommandMessage) => message.channel.id === process.env.NUMBER_CHANNEL_ID);
```

This will tell the dispatcher to block the command if the result of the arrow function returns true.